# React - component will not render in foreach loop?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

I have a small application when you open a tab the React Route redirects to the given component (container). And from the container i want to render the child components. I use the foreach loop to go through a list that has the props that need to be given to the child. However, the child doesn't get rendered.

I don't want to use map because i use libraries that depend on the list class.

```
render() {   
    return ( 
        <div>
            {this.state.list.ForEach((element) => 
                <ChildComponent childName={element.name} 
        }
        </div> 
    );
}
```

}

Answer (score 61):

You are confusing [Array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) with [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). `forEach` does not return anything. The correct way is:

```
<div>
    {this.state.list.map((element, index) => 
        <ChildComponent key={index} childName={element.name} />
    )}
</div>
```

`map` converts the given `element` into another element, a component in this case. The result of calling `map` is an array of components that is then rendered. `forEach` always returns `undefined` therefore the result of your code is the same as writing:

```
<div>
   {undefined}
</div>
```

Note that `key` is also necessary when rendering lists of components.

Comment: I am using map but still face the same issue. The element is of type `never` even though it has values.